# Definition of Uniform Convergence for vector-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Birkhoff and Rota's 'Ordinary Differential Equations' proves that Picard iteration works not just for scalar differential equations but for the systems of scalar DEs that arise from vector-valued differential equations as well.  (That is, DEs of the form $\frac{d\mathbf{f}}{dt} = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{f},t)$, where $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{F}$ are vector-valued.)  The proof relies on the notion of uniform convergence, but I'm unable to find a definition for uniform convergence for vector-valued functions.  By analogy with Wikipedia's definition for uniform convergence for functions whose range is simply in $\mathbb{R}$, I've gone ahead and made my own definition:

Let $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be functions such that $f_i$ is defined for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.  We say that $(f_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is **uniformly convergent** with limit $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $K$ such that for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and all $k \geq K$ we have $\|f(\mathbf{x})_k - f(\mathbf{x})\| < \epsilon$.

Is this correct, or close to correct?

Comment: That is perfectly correct.

Comment: Well, except for the (now corrected typo).  Would you like to write an answer of some sort so I can accept it (and you get the credit, if that matters to you)?

Comment: Needless: you guessed  the right answer, I just confirmed you guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bernard has confirmed that the definition I gave is correct.